# Installing custom fonts in Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm having an issue installing a custom font (from [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/)) in Xcode 4.6.3. I am doing the following:

1. Downloading my font from Google Fonts
2. Installing it on my mac so that I can get its system name
3. drag my font file (Inconsolata.ttf) into the "Supporting Files" folder in Xcode
4. Go to my `Info.Plist` file and add Inconsolata.tff as an item in the UIAppFonts array.
5. try to print out my installed fonts in the list of fonts using
6. try to use my custom font with ***it's full name, which I found in Finder***

**step 5: print out All UIFonts:**

```
// When I search for "Inconsolata" in my Debug Console, it returns nothing
// Therefore I think that the font simply isn't being installed...
 for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
    }
}
```

**step 6: use custom UIFont:**

```
// this line  doesn't work.
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Inconsolata" size:15];

// this line works. it changes font to Helvetica-Bold
// cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by adding target when adding font file, like so

[image]